# Process Group Id in UNIX

Tags: perl, bash

I am trying to do some process control in a script (bash). For this reason I output the process group id of the current process to a file.

```
ps ax -o '%p %r'|perl -ne 'if ($_ =~ /\s*$$\s*(\d+)/) { print "$1"; exit; }' > $pgidfile
nohup $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp somejar.jar some.java.Program & > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I have also tried:

```
ps ax -o '%p %r'|awk '/'"$$"' [0-9]+/ {print $2}' > $pgidfile
nohup $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp somejar.jar some.java.Program & > /dev/null 2>&1
```

However in both these cases, the file (in $pgidfile) seems to be empty. (Although on certain rare occasions it does seem to have the correct value.) Also, just running the commands(to output the process group id - option 1 or option 2 above) themselves on the commandline seem to do the right thing.

It would be great if someone could suggest a solution to the above problem or answer either (or both) of the following questions:

1) What is the suggested way to get a process's group id in a shell or perl script?

2) Does running a command under nohup change the output redirection of previous/subsequent commands that aren't related to the command executed with nohup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) What is the suggested way to get a process's group id in a shell or perl script?

An improvement to your current approach would be to do an *exact field match* on the PID you care about.  Any unanchored regex technique (such as your original post) runs the risk of matching the wrong thing.  If $$ happens to be 123, you'll match `ps` output lines for PIDs 1123, 1234, etc.

Now, `awk` and `perl` are both very good at processing field delimited input (see [perl's `-a` switch](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2a-a%2a)), but you don't need to do that, since you can limit `ps` to just the process you care about:

```
$ ps -o '%r' $$ | tail -n 1 > $pgfile
```

Find out how your `ps` can be told to omit headers, and you can remove `tail` from that pipeline.

> 2) Does running a command under nohup change the output redirection of previous/subsequent commands that aren't related to the command executed with nohup?

No.  Something else is amiss in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses. I used pilcrow's suggestion (or a slight variant: ps -o pgrp= $$, which suppresses the header) and so accepted his answer - I suppose the other approaches are valid answers too.

Comment: Doesn't work in Mac Terminal bash v3.2.57 (MacOS 10.13.2)

Comment: @EgbertS, what "doesn't work" on OS X?  The _ps_ invocation?  The [portable invocation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html) would be `ps -o pgid= $$`.  (However the OP is likely using the Linux _ps_, which supports non-standard format specifiers like _pgrp_ and AIX's _%r_.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of resorting to awkward shell scripting and `ps`, why don't you have your Java program get its own pgid?  In the worst case, you can do this in a one-line JNI method.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps ax -o '%p %r' | awk -vp=$$ '$0~p{print $2}'
```

Comment: I think you want `awk -vp=$$ '$1==p{print $2}'`, lest $$ := 123 match records with PID 51230 or PGID 4123.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, you can get a process's real group id with `$(`, and its effective group id with `$)`. See [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Comment: Correction: effective group is `$)`. Also, this is not what the OP is asking about (process groups - PGID). Your answer is about a process's group memberships (GID).